# Measuring the extent of entanglement in tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a non-negative integer valued grading function on the tensor product of two Hilbert spaces which measures the extent of entanglement ?

Comment: Where "entaglement" means...

Comment: In finite dimensions there is the tensor rank.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an integer-valued function, you likely want the [Schmidt rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) (which is equal to the tensor rank mentioned by Qiaochu Yuan in the case of two Hilbert spaces) if you're dealing with vectors in a (finite-dimensional) Hilbert space.

If you're working with operators acting *on* the tensor product of two Hilbert spaces, you probably want the Schmidt number, which is the natural extension of the Schmidt rank to mixed states. See [arXiv:quant-ph/9911117](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9911117) for the definition and basic properties.